# No Simple Group of Order 144

Tags: group-theory

I see the proof here: http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/no-simple-groups-of-order-144-525-2025-or-3159-exist/, but I can't follow it, so could someone please explain to me how this proof works?  Or maybe offer an alternative proof?

Comment: I understand the Sylow theorems very well, I'm just confused on where they bring 5! into play and then look at the intersection of P3 and Q3

Comment: Usually for these kinds of proofs, I can just take the smallest np such that np=/=1, then show that the minimum number of elements in the group exceeds the order of the group, so at least one sylow p-subgroup must be np=1, so the group is not simple.  Obviously, we can't do that for this proof, so I'm pretty confused on what they do and why.

Comment: Taking the regular action of $\;G\;$ on the set of left cosets of a subgroup $\;H\;$ of index $\;n\;$ ,  and then taking the corresponding homomorphism $\;\phi:G\to S_n\;$ , we have that $\;\ker\phi\;$ is the maximal normal subgroup of $\;G\;$ contained in $\;H\;$ (this is *the core* of $\;H\;$). If $\;G\;$ is simple it must be $\;\ker\phi=1\iff G\;$ can be embedded in $\;S_n\;$, and in the proof's case that's impossible since $\;|G|\nmid 120=5!=|S_5|\;$ , so that no subgroup of index less than $\;5\;$ is possible...

Comment: There is a duplicate, see my answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590161/intersection-of-two-finite-abelian-subgroups/590808#590808

Comment: Dear @NickyHekster : The subject matter is indeed duplicate, but we usually distinguish between posts that *ask the question* and ones that *ask for help understanding the proof of the question*. For this reason, I wouldn't vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I did not ask for votes ... maybe in the wording "duplicate" should have been "similar question"

Answer (score 3):

Both of the things you're asking about could be classified as part of the game of eliminating possibilities. No doubt you already knew that, but maybe the specific strategies they applied were things you hadn't thought about before.

### The $n!$ trick eliminates subgroups of low index:

Suppose $G$ had a subgroup $H$ of index $k$ with $1<k\leq 5$. Then $G$ can act on the cosets of $H$ in the obvious way. If the group were simple, then the kernel of the action would be trivial, and $G$ would have to embed into $Sym(k)$. But the proof is pointing out that $G$ can't embed in $Sym(k)$ since $|G|\not||Sym(k)|=k!$

In this way, they are able to eliminate the $3$ and $4$ case. The reason he said five and not six is that $2^3|6$. S/He could just as well have said "$4!$" and eliminated the $3$ and $4$ case in the same way.

### Looking at intersections of $p$-Sylows can be a good way to force a large normalizer

The index of $N_G(P_3\cap Q_3)$, must be in $\{1,2,4,8\}$ considering the order of $G$ and that the normalizer contains $3$-Sylow subgroups. We eliminated $2,4$ in the last paragraph. $1$ doesn't work because if that were the case, you would have a normal subgroup of order $3$, which when multiplied by any $2$-sylow would result in a subgroup of index $3$ (not allowed.) (The author of that page doesn't seem to have eliminated this case.) So the only option left is $8$.

Applying Sylow theory again to the normalizer, there can be only one $3$-Sylow: but this contradicts the fact that both $Q_3$ and $P_3$ are there. So all the alternatives are exhausted, and $G$ must have a normal $2$-Sylow subgroup or a normal $3$-Sylow subgroup.

So again: what's useful about $p$-Sylow intersections? At least in small cases like this ($p^2$) it's an easy way to pull those two Sylows into a single subgroup of $G$ which share a normal subgroup. This generally produces a group of smaller order which you can reanalyze. If it is in fact the whole group, then you have a normal subgroup with which to produce other subgroups, hopefully of low index (because you hopefully have already ruled out low index subgroups.)

In case you haven't read it before, there is a refined version of the basic Sylow theorems that takes into consideration intersections of Sylows. You can find the statement [here on page 59](http://books.google.com/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&pg=PA57&dq=isaacs+algebra+sylow&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NKuoUpCCPaa_sQTJ6oKwAQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=isaacs%20algebra%20sylow&f=false). I didn't see that it was applicable in this particular case, but it's still worth knowing.