# Group of order $432$ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

How do we prove that a group $G$ of order $432=2^4\cdot 3^3$ is not simple?

Here are my attempts:
Let $n_3$ be the number of Sylow 3-subgroups.
Then, by Sylow's Third Theorem, $n_3\mid 16$ and $n_3\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.
Thus, $n_3=1, 4$ or 16.

Next, let $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be two distinct 3-subgroups such that $|Q_1\cap Q_2|$ is maximum.

If $|Q_1\cap Q_2|=1$, then we can conclude $n_3\equiv 1\pmod {3^3}$, which will force $n_3=1$ and we are done.

If $|Q_1\cap Q_2|=3$, similarly we can conclude $n_3\equiv 1\pmod {3^2}$, and we are done.

The problem occurs when $|Q_1\cap Q_2|=3^2$, we can only conclude $n_3\equiv 1\pmod 3$ which is of no help.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note first the following: if $G$ is a simple group of and $H$ is subgroup of index $n$, then $|G|$ divides $n!$ (see I.M. Isaacs, [Finite Group Theory](http://bit.ly/1L1iKtp), Corollary 1.3).

This implies that if $G$ is a simple group of order $432$ and $H$ is a proper subgroup of $2$-power index, one must have $|G:H|=16$.

Now we proceed where you left off: let $Q_1$, $Q_2 \in Syl_3(G)$,  $|Q_1 \cap Q_2|=9$. Then $Q_1 \cap Q_2 \lhd Q_1$ (the index of $Q_1 \cap Q_2$ is the smallest prime dividing $|Q_1|$). Hence $Q_1 \subseteq N_G(Q_1 \cap Q_2)$. Note that $N_G(Q_1 \cap Q_2)$ must be proper, since $Q_1 \cap Q_2$ cannot be normal in $G$. It follows by the observation above that $|G:N_G(Q_1 \cap Q_2)|=16$. But then we conclude that actually $Q_1=N_G(Q_1 \cap Q_2)$. By the same reasoning, $Q_2=N_G(Q_1 \cap Q_2)$. So $Q_1=Q_2$, a contradiction to $|Q_1 \cap Q_2|=9$.

Comment: Brilliant and well presented answer! I managed to understand your explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, you are welcome!

Comment: Isn't it much simpler to just conclude that G has a subgroup of order 2(you just need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) and then you know, all groups of order 2 are normal, so G is not simple.

Comment: @Everstudent No, in general subgroups of order $2$ are not normal (e.g. any subgroup generated by a $2$-cycle in $S_3$). Subgroups of *index* $2$ are normal.

Comment: Yeah, because index 2 means only 2 cosets, but for index 2 we need order 216, which is not a Prime, so we can't do what I suggested... Do not know why I mistook order for index.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a simple group of order $432$. Note that $|G|$ does not divide $8!$, thus no proper subgroup of $G$ has index at most $8$. Sylow’s Theorem forces $n_3(G) = 16 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 9$, so that there exist $P_3, Q_3 \in \mathsf{Syl}_3(G)$ such that $|N_G(P_3 \cap Q_3)|$ is divisible by $3^3$ and another prime. Thus $|N_G(P_3 \cap Q_3)| \in \{ 3^3 \cdot 2, 3^3 \cdot 2^2, 3^3 \cdot 2^2, 3^3 \cdot 2^3, 3^3 \cdot 2^4 \}$. In each case either $P_3 \cap Q_3$ is normal in $G$ or its normalizer has sufficiently small index.

Remark. For more details on the steps see [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/there-are-no-finite-simple-groups-of-even-order-less-than-500-except-for-the-orders-2-60-168-and-360/).

Comment: May I ask what is Lemma 13? I found the crazy project website but did not understand it. If you are the creator of crazy project I must thank you though as it has enlightened me many times.

Comment: No, I have nothing to do with this project. You are right, Lemma $13$ is missing. You can find help about the proof given in the "crazy project" also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601613/no-simple-group-of-order-144); it works the same way for $n=432$. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590161/intersection-of-two-finite-abelian-subgroups/590808#590808).