# Prove that there is no simple group of order $144$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I was reading the following proof for that question (Joanpemos' answer)-

[How to prove a group of order $144$ is not simple using Normalizers of Sylow intersections.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727781/how-to-prove-a-group-of-order-144-is-not-simple-using-normalizers-of-sylow-int)

And I understood it well up to the part where he says that the intersection of the sylow subgroups $P,Q$ is of size $3$.

Why is that?

Also, why the fact that these groups are abelian, means that the normalizer has at least $6+9$ elements?

Comment: Did he not explain that if all the intersections of Sylow $3$-subgroups were trivial then there union has 129 elements leaving room for only a single Sylow 2-subgroup? If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two Sylow-3 subgroups with $K=P_1\cap P_2$ of order three, then $K\unlhd P_1$ and $K\unlhd P_2$, so $N_G(K)$ contains both $P_1$ and $P_2$, hence has at least 15 elements.

Comment: Oh, and all groups of order $p^2$, $p$ a prime, are abelian.

Comment: But why the intersection is of size $3$?? And if $N_G(K)$ contains both $P_1,P_2$ shouldn't it be of size at least $9+9=18$?

Comment: The intersecrion is a subgroup of both, so its size is a factor of $9$ by Lagrange. Also $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ for any sets $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a completely elementary solution.  By Sylow there are 1, 4, or 16 3-Sylow subgroups.  It can't be 1 (then the 3-Sylow would be normal), and it can't be 4 (then there would be a non-trivial homomorphism to $S_4$ given by the conjugation action on the 4 3-Sylows, and the kernel would be a non-trivial normal subgroup).  So there are 16 3-Sylows.

If any two of them intersect in a subgroup $H$ of size 3, then the centralizer $C$ of $H$ contains both of those 3-Sylows, and thus, by Sylow, either 4 or 16 3-Sylows.  If $C$ contains 16 3-Sylows, it's the whole group, and $H$, being central is a non-trivial normal subgroup.  Thus, $C$ contains 4 3-Sylows.  But then $36\le |C|<144$, so $|C|$ is 72 or 36, and there is a non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $S_2$ or $S_4$, given by the action of $G$ on cosets of $C$.  The kernel is a non-trivial normal subgroup.

Thus, all the 3-Sylows have trivial pairwise intersections.  That means there are $8\cdot16=128$ elements of order 3 or 9.  The remaining 16 elements thus must be the unique 2-Sylow, which is therefore normal.  Contradiction.

Comment: Why the kernel must be non-trivial?

Comment: Well, with the homomorphisms to $S_2$ and $S_4$, the actions are transitive (so that the kernel is not $G$) and $|G|>|S_4|$ (respectively, $|G|>|S_2|$), so the kernels cannot just be the identity either.